# Order by a child object

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql, force.com

The below query pulls the result on **Account** and uses two inner queries on child objects **Monthly_cc__c** and **Yearly_cc__c**. I would like to sort the result by Processing date of the **monthly_cc__c**. Please help

```
   Select  id,
    (SELECT Country__c, Current_Month_Active__c, 
            Distributor__c,Personal_CC_MTD__c, Total_CC_MTD__c, 
            Processing_Date__c, Total_Active_CC_MTD__c, 
            Non_Manager_CC_MTD__c,Leadership_CC_MTD__c, Processing_Month__c, 
            Processing_Year__c, Global_Case_Credits__c, 
            Eagle_Manager_Global_New_CC__c, Chairmans_Bonus_Global_New_CC__c 
     FROM Account.Monthly_CCs__r 
     WHERE   Processing_Month__c IN ( 9,8,7)  AND Op_Company__c = 'GBR'  ),
    (SELECT Total_CC_YTD__c, Total_Active_CC_YTD__c, Non_Manager_CC_YTD__c,
            Leadership_Qualification_CC_YTD__c,Operating_Company__c 
     FROM Account.Yearly_CCs__r 
     WHERE Operating_Company__c= 'GBR'   AND Processing_Date__c =2016-01-01) 
   From Account where ID IN 
     ('001d000001VpPcyAAF','001d000001liZH4AAM','001d000001Q5sflAAB' )
```

Comment: What are you trying to sort? The records from the sub-query or the Id's from the Account?

Comment: I am trying to sort the sub query processing_dare__c on account.monthly_cc__c

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you want to sort in the SUB query you have two options:

1. Create a formula field with the field you want to Sort `Account__r.Monthly_CC__c` then simply add an `ORDER BY` SOQL clause with the new formula field
2. Add `ORDER BY` SOQL clause with `Account__r.Monthly_CC__c`